# How to create card item with bottom shape as image (has shadow effect)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to create card item with bottom shape as image (has shadow effect)?
[Image preview](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WrcpHb_sPXvHV3F1SwLELo781t8zt0zf/view)

```
.curved-shape {
     height: 400px;
     width: 400px;
     position: relative;
     background-color: #522d5b;
}
.curved-shape:after {
    content: '';
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -50px;
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 69px 0 0 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 red;
}
```

How to create card item with bottom shape as image (has shadow effect)?

Comment: you may want to find information about `background-image`. I don't understand what shadow effect you are referring to in the image

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do the entire shape as an SVG and then use a `drop-shadow`-filter on that shape, something like this:

```css
.container {
  height: 100px; width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

#gradient {
  --color-stop1: #f12c06;
  --color-stop2: #faed34;
}

svg {
  fill: url(#gradient) #fff;
  stroke: 0;
  width: 100%;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4));
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="gradient" x2="0.35" y2="1">
          <stop offset="0%" stop-color="var(--color-stop1)" />
          <stop offset="30%" stop-color="var(--color-stop1)" />
          <stop offset="100%" stop-color="var(--color-stop2)" />
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <path d="M-143.82-117.74a23.11 23.11 0 0 1 23.2-23.01H118.7a25.02 25.02 0 0 1 25.12 24.92v252.28a4.3 4.3 0 0 1-2.68 3.98 4.35 4.35 0 0 1-4.73-.95l-18.84-18.85-3.7-3.69a57.24 57.24 0 0 0-40.47-16.73h-194.1a23.03 23.03 0 0 1-23.12-22.93z" transform="matrix(1.04 0 0 1.05 150 147.95)" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
  </svg>
  
  <div class="content">
    <p>Some text comes here as content of your "custom" shape card.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

There are of course limitations like dynamic height of that card for example which are not easily solved with this approach, but if you want to apply a shadow to a custom-path (curved) element like you have it in your design, it's going to be very difficult without using SVG's as you'll be dealing with separate elements, that are "physically" boxes in nature. That means if you apply box-shadow to any of those boxes it won't give you the result you are looking for. This is because non-SVG elements only know box-shadow or text-shadow, only SVG can do drop-shadows that follow along a custom path.